# Could I color a string from point a to point b?

Tags: python, string, colorama

This is purely out of curiosity, if I were to have a string with a hyperlink like `"In July 2019, the fashion and sneaker trading platform <a href="https://stockx.com/news/update-on-data-security-issue/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">StockX suffered a data breach</a> which was subsequently sold via a dark webmarketplace."`

If I used the colorama module `red = Fore.RED`, is it possible to only color the string from part a to part b? In this case it's `"<a"` to `"</a>"`. So essentially just this part `"<a href="https://stockx.com/news/update-on-data-security-issue/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">StockX suffered a data breach</a>"`

Edit: Sorry for the confusion everyone, what I meant by my question, is that I wanted to know if I could still print out the whole string, but only have the `"<a href="https://stockx.com/news/update-on-data-security-issue/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">StockX suffered a data breach</a>"` part highlighted red.

Comment: You need to print `Fore.RED` before the point you want to start coloring, and `Fore.RESET` after the point you want to reset the color to normal... That said, AFAIK `colorama` is for coloring terminal output, and clearly you're dealing with HTML... are you printing the HTML to a terminal or showing it in a browser? If the latter, look into CSS and the HTML `style` tag. `colorama` is not going to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

To print to terminal with **Colorama** satisfying your request.

You do:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style

str = f"""
In July 2019, the fashion and sneaker trading platform {Fore.RED}<a  href="https://stockx.com/news/update-on-data-security-issue/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{Style.RESET_ALL} StockX suffered a data breach</a> which was subsequently sold via a dark webmarketplace.
"""
print(str)
```

This works, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Colorama is for [terminal output](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/#:%7E:text=for%20producing%20colored%20terminal%20text)

If you are printing it over on terminal, yeah Colorama can be used as follows,

```
from colorama import Fore, Style
print("In July 2019, the fashion and sneaker trading platform",Fore.RED,"<a href='https://stockx.com/news/update-on-data-security-issue/' target='_blank' rel='noopener'>StockX suffered a data breach</a>",Style.RESET, "which was subsequently sold via a dark webmarketplace.")
```

Though I don't see the point of that.

If not, and you want to render an html, then `style="color:red"` must be used in `<a>`, anchor tag.